# Where do you get poker videos?

Tags: wsop

I would like to watch Big One For One Drop 2014. I would like to get all the videos if possible but I am not sure where to get those. Tried to search with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually find that specialist site [PokerTube](http://www.pokertube.com) has links to videos of the major events like the "Big One for 1Drop", "WSOP", etc.

Other than that, youtube *eventually* has them.

Comment: but where they get those videos from?

Comment: They might get them from torrents or something and upload it to their site. In any way, pokertube has always been by far the best video site for poker!

Answer (score 2):

So far there are only a few episodes out. You can watch the first one here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAVvDC6Bnyg.